# Spark SQL in PySpark throws ParseError Exception

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark code running in an AWS glue job. I have some temporary tables created from dataframes in the same code using the function createOrReplaceTempView().
I am running a multiline SQL query within the code to fetch data from these temporary tables and store in a dataframe. However, I am getting ParseError Exception. The same query runs absolutely fine in a SQL client. Below is the query. Can someone please help? Unfortunately I don't get any error message other than the text "ParseError Exception"

```
def getSCMCaseHistLanding(self):
        landingDF = self.spark.sql("""SELECT aud.case_id,
             r.name                                                                                                        AS          role_name,
             cas.account_id,
             cas.created_time                                                                                              AS          case_created_time,
             cas.last_updated_time,
             cas.screening_decision,
             aud.created_time                                                                                              AS          record_created_time,
             aud.username,
             row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY aud.case_id ORDER BY date_trunc('minute', aud.created_time) + date_part('second', aud.created_time)::INT / 10 * INTERVAL '10 sec') rank,
             max(CASE WHEN field = 'status_id' THEN aud.value ELSE NULL END)                                               AS          d_status,
             max(CASE WHEN field = 'status_id' THEN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(aud.description, 'from ', 2), ' to', 1) ELSE NULL END) AS src_status,
             max(CASE WHEN lower(field) = 'annotation' THEN [value] ELSE NULL END)                                         AS          annotation,
             max(CASE WHEN lower(field) = 'reason_id' THEN [value] ELSE NULL END)                                          AS          reason,
             max(CASE WHEN lower(field) = 'approver_id' THEN [value] ELSE NULL END)                                        AS          approver,
             r.team_name                                                                                                   AS          approver_source,
             max(CASE WHEN lower(field) = 'decision_id' THEN [value] ELSE NULL END)                                        AS          decision,
             max(CASE WHEN field = 'status_id' THEN aud.created_time ELSE NULL END)                                        AS          lsd,
             last_value(lsd IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY aud.case_id ORDER BY record_created_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS          last_status_changed_date,
             max(CASE WHEN aud.field = 'assigned_to' THEN REVERSE(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(aud.value), ' ', 1)) ELSE NULL END)   AS          assigned_to_t,
             last_value(assigned_to_t IGNORE NULLS)
             OVER (PARTITION BY aud.case_id ORDER BY record_created_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS          assigned_to,
             max(CASE WHEN aud.field = 'assigned_to' THEN aud.username ELSE NULL END)                                  AS          assigned_by,
             max(CASE
                     WHEN (aud.field = 'assigned_to' AND aud.description LIKE 'Workbasket%') OR
                          (aud.field = 'assigned_to' AND aud.description LIKE '%by%') THEN 'Auto Assign'
                     WHEN aud.field = 'assigned_to' AND aud.description LIKE '%themself%' THEN 'Get Next'
                 END)                                                                                                      AS          assignment_method,
             max(
                     CASE WHEN aud.field = 'assigned_to' THEN aud.description ELSE NULL END)                               AS          assignment_detail,
             max(CASE WHEN lower(field) = 'state_id' THEN [value] ELSE NULL END)                                           AS          ll_state,
             last_value(d_status IGNORE NULLS)
             OVER (PARTITION BY aud.case_id ORDER BY record_created_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS          dest_status,
             last_value(ll_state IGNORE NULLS)
             OVER (PARTITION BY aud.case_id ORDER BY record_created_time ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS          l_state,
             CASE WHEN l_state IS NULL THEN 'Open' ELSE l_state END                                                        AS          state,
             max(CASE WHEN lower(field) = 'responsive_action_id' THEN [value] ELSE NULL END)                                                                                        AS          responsive_action,
             max(CASE WHEN type_name = 'Language' THEN skill.skill_name ELSE NULL END)                                 AS          language_skill,
             max(
                     CASE WHEN type_name = 'Business' THEN skill.skill_name ELSE NULL END)                                 AS          business_skill,
             max(CASE
                     WHEN lower(field) = 'annotation' AND lower(value) LIKE 'f+ applied by jarvis%' THEN 'jarvis'
                     WHEN lower(field) = 'annotation' AND (lower(value) LIKE '%bulk action%'
                         OR lower(value) LIKE '%moving cases to invalid data%') THEN 'bulk action'
                     WHEN lower(field) = 'annotation' AND lower(value) LIKE '%t+ decision recommended by scr model%'
                         THEN 'SCR T+ Model'
                     WHEN lower(field) = 'annotation' AND lower(value) LIKE '%f+ applied by scr model%'
                         THEN 'SCR F+ Model'
                     ELSE NULL END)                                                                                        AS          source_of_action,
             max(CASE
                     WHEN lower(field) = 'annotation' AND lower(value) LIKE '%duplicate case%' THEN 'Y'
                     ELSE 'N' END)                                                                                         AS          duplicate_case,
             max(CASE
                     WHEN field = 'state_id' AND aud.description = 'Case reopened' THEN
                             date_trunc('minute', aud.created_time) +
                             date_part('second', aud.created_time)::INT / 10 * INTERVAL '10 sec'
                     ELSE NULL END)                                                                                        AS          case_reopened_time,
             max(0)                                                                                                        AS          active_record_flag
      FROM cm_spectre_case_audit aud
               JOIN cm_spectre_case cas
                    ON cas.case_id = aud.case_id
               LEFT JOIN v_cm_user_snapshot u ON
                  CASE
                      WHEN aud.field = 'assigned_to' THEN REVERSE(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(aud.value), ' ', 1))
                      ELSE aud.username
                      END = u.alias AND aud.created_time BETWEEN u.start_time AND u.end_time
               LEFT JOIN cm_role r ON u.current_role_id = r.role_id
               LEFT JOIN cm_lookup_skills lookup_skill ON lookup_skill.case_id = cas.case_id
               LEFT JOIN cm_skill skill ON skill.skill_id = lookup_skill.skill_id
               LEFT JOIN cm_skill_type skill_type ON skill_type.type_id = skill.type_id
      WHERE 1 = 1
        AND NOT (field = 'created_time'
          AND username = 'System')
        AND NOT (field = 'annotation'
          AND username = 'System')
        AND NOT (field = 'skill_name_')
        AND NOT (field = 'assigned_to'
          AND lower(aud.description) LIKE '%unassigned%')
        AND NOT (field = 'attachment')
        AND NOT (field = 'accept_list_id')
        AND NOT (field LIKE 'screening_match_id%')
      GROUP BY aud.case_id, cas.account_id, role_name, r.team_name, cas.created_time, cas.last_updated_time,
               cas.screening_decision,
               aud.created_time,
               aud.username
""")
        return landingDF
```

Comment: The error message may not be helpful to you, but it may be to someone here. Please include the **complete, exact** error message. While you're making that [edit], please edit your title as well. If you remove the redundant tag information (which should not be in the title at all), it leaves *throws parseerror exception*, which provides little or no information about your question. The title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately there's no error message at all. All it says is "ParseException:"  nothing else. Hence I put the same in the subject as well.

Comment: Your SQL query contains constructs that are not recognized by Spark SQL, for example the `::` cast operator. You should adapt the query to run it through Spark SQL. But as already suggested by @Ken White you should find the full error, Spark will tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @vinsce! That's good to know, I will replace this by Spark SQL equivalent constructs. Re the error message, I only get "ParseException" in the output of the AWS glue job in which I am running this code. Pardon my ignorance here, I am very new to the engineering field. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How to find the logs depends on the specific infrastructure. Since you are on AWS, your place for logs is CloudWatch. You can take a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging.html), but you definitely have to find a way to see the logs, not just for this error. It will especially help you to debug apps. If necessary you can ask a specific question on how to find the logs for your deployment.